# error in making the file: expected primary-expression before ')' token

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

I have a struct defined as:

```
template<typename T>
struct unique_owned_item_filter: public std::unary_function<T,bool> {

  unique_owned_item_filter(){}

  bool operator()(const T& item)const {
    return !item->shared() ||  item->owner() == MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();
  }

  typedef T item_type;

};
```

and I want to use this structure in a function like this

```
 void read_nodes(std::ifstream& infile, mesh_type& mesh, const std::list<int>&my_nodes)
  {

  typedef typename mesh_type::node_t nd_t;
..... follows some code .....
  create_double_nodes(mesh,unique_owned_item_filter<nd_t>);
}
```

where the function create_double_nodes is defined as

```
template<typename mesh_type, typename rule_type >
void create_double_nodes(mesh_type& mesh,rule_type& rule){
 .... follows some code ....
}
```

When I pass to `create_double_nodes` the argument `unique_owned_item_filter` I insert
its dependence on the template parameter `nd_t`, that, in my case, is the mesh node 
of type `mesh_type::node_t`.

When I compile the whole, I get the error `expected primary-expression before ')' token at the declaration of create_double_nodes(mesh,unique_owned_item_filter<nd_t>);`.
It seems to me that the template argument is right.
Can somebody help me?

The problem in the definition of the create_double_nodes disappeared, but now the problem appeared inside the body of the function itself.

```
template<typename mesh_type, typename rule_type >
void create_double_nodes(mesh_type& mesh, const rule_type& rule){
typename mesh_type::nd_set_t::const_iterator it_first( mesh.nodes().begin());
while(it_first!=mesh.nodes().end()){
if(rule(*it_first))
....follows code ....
it_first++
}
```

when i apply the rule to the const iterator it does not accept it. The compilation gives the following error:

no match for call to '(const GALES::unique_owned_item_filter, 5, GALES::base_5_dofs> >) (GALES::fem_node, 5, GALES::base_5_dofs>* const&)'

with candidates

```
bool GALES::unique_owned_item_filter<T>::operator()(const T&) const [with T =     GALES::fem_node<GALES::geometric_node<2>, 5, GALES::base_5_dofs>]
```

where

```
GALES::fem_node<GALES::geometric_node<2>, 5, GALES::base_5_dofs>
```

is the complete type of node of the mesh.
I cannot understand why the rule applied to a constant iterator is not accepted. If you need more details I will try to explain it better.
Thank you very much again.

Comment: how is sample `mesh_type` defined ?

Comment: because it [works when simplified](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c818a328bae37862)

Answer (score 3):

`unique_owned_item_filter<nd_t>` is a *type,* but you're using it as a function argument, where a *value* is required. You probably wanted to create an object of this type instead:

```
create_double_nodes(mesh, unique_owned_item_filter<nd_t>());
//                                                      ^^ parens here!
```

This will not work as-is, though, because your function template `create_double_nodes` takes the second parameter by non-const reference, and such cannot bind to a temporary (such as the one created in my example above).

You have two solutions: either change `create_double_nodes` to take its parameter by const-reference, or create a named object for the argument:

```
unique_owned_item_filter<nd_t> filter;
create_double_nodes(mesh, filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Make it an object:

```
 create_double_nodes(mesh,unique_owned_item_filter<nd_t>());
                                                        ^^
```

2.Pass by const reference or value:

```
void create_double_nodes(mesh_type& mesh, const rule_type& rule){
                                          ^^^^^
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested me, and everything is now working on that part of the code. However, problem appeared inside the function create_double_nodes. I will append the new problem editing the first question above

Comment: @AntonellaLongo: ok, will take a look